# ViewModel update failed with error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2015

I am having following ViewModel, and corresponding two models.

I am displaying data from this ViewModel on a view, but when I post data to update, following error occurs

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WebMSM.Models.ComplainDetailsVm', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebMSM.Models.REPAIRING'.

```
public partial class ComplainDetailsVm
{

    public virtual REPAIRING REPAIRINGs { get; set; }
    public virtual COMPLAIN COMPLAINs { get; set; }
}
```

**REPAIRING.cs**

```
public partial class REPAIRING
{

    [Key]
    [DisplayName("JOBSHEET NO")]
    public int JOBSHEET_NO { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("IN TIME")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> IN_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("CREATE TIME")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CREATE_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("LAST EDIT TIME")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
}
```

**COMPLAIN.cs**

```
public partial class COMPLAIN
{

    [Key]
    [DisplayName("JOBSHEET NO")]
    public int JOBSHEET_NO { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("COMPANY NAME")]
    public string COMPANY_NAME { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("MODEL NAME")]
    public string MODEL_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER ACTION**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id,ComplainDetailsVm model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var r = model.REPAIRINGs;
            var c = model.COMPLAINs;
            db.Entry(r).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }    
        return View(model);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

**VIEW**

```
@model WebMSM.Models.ComplainDetailsVm


@{
ViewBag.Title = "EditRepairingComplain";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.REPAIRINGs.JOBSHEET_NO)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.COMPLAINs.JOBSHEET_NO)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COMPLAINs.COMPANY_NAME, 

htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.COMPLAINs.COMPANY_NAME, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COMPLAINs.COMPANY_NAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COMPLAINs.MODEL_NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.COMPLAINs.MODEL_NAME, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COMPLAINs.MODEL_NAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.REPAIRINGs.IN_TIMESTAMP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.REPAIRINGs.IN_TIMESTAMP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.REPAIRINGs.IN_TIMESTAMP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.REPAIRINGs.CREATE_TIMESTAMP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.REPAIRINGs.CREATE_TIMESTAMP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.REPAIRINGs.CREATE_TIMESTAMP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.REPAIRINGs.LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.REPAIRINGs.LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.REPAIRINGs.LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>







        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-6">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**UPDATE ADDED GET METHOD**

```
// GET: Repairing/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {





        var vm = new ComplainDetailsVm();
        var r = db.REPAIRINGs.Find(id);
        var c = db.COMPLAINs.Find(id);
        if (r != null)
        {
            vm.REPAIRINGs = r;
            vm.COMPLAINs = c;


        }
        //ViewData["LIST_ESTIMATE_AMOUNT_OK_FROM_CUSTOMER"] = lstOKNOTOK;
        return View("EditRepairingComplain",vm);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: The error message is self explanatory - your passing an instance of `ComplainDetailsVm` to a view which has `@model WebMSM.Models.REPAIRING` - Change one or the other so they match

Comment: I am adding view for your explanation. I am adding correct model to the view.

Comment: You need to show your GET method. The view you have shown has nothing at all to do with the error.

Comment: Your GET method is returning a view named `EditRepairingComplain.cshtml` and your POST method is returning a view named `Edit.cshtml` - which view have your shown? One of them has `@model WebMSM.Models.REPAIRING`

Comment: Ohh, my mistake. You are right. I was returning `Edit.cshtml` after post and save. I changed it accordingly and now its working fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can I ask you something more?. In  `IN_TIMESTAMP` textbox, if I put a button besides and I want to set current server time in that textbox on button click, what will be the code for that?

Comment: Both methods should be returning `Edit.cshtml` and `Edit.cshtml` should have `@model WebMSM.Models.ComplainDetailsVm` (what is the point of retruning a different named view?). And since your POST method is not even doing anything with your instance of `COMPLAIN` then you have a design problem anyway - your `COMPLAIN` html should be generated by using `@Html.Action()` in the view that calls a child action only method.

Comment: You can add the time of returning server time as a DateTime object to your view model, but if you want the time of your button click, you can use an ajax method to update the textbox.

Comment: As for `IN_TIMESTAMP` - your DONT. You should be using a view model that does not contain any of those properties (`CREATE_TIMESTAMP`, `LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP ` etc). You set them in the POST method before your save the data model.

Comment: Very helpful information by both of you.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your `View`s recognize your `ViewModel` in two ways: you can have the MVC framework figure that out for you, or you can use [strongly typed views](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views)

In your case, your view is strongly typed but refers to the wrong object class. This can happen if you copied your view from some other file. You should see the following line on your cshtml file:

```
@model WebMSM.Models.REPAIRING
```

replace this with:

```
@model WebMSM.Models.ComplainDetailsVm
```

and you should no longer get the error.

Edit:

worth to mention that these lines should be on top of the `cshtml` file returned by the action methods.

Comment: I have already updated my question with view. It already contains `@model WebMSM.Models.ComplainDetailsVm`

Comment: in your post action method, do you return also `return View("EditRepairingComplain",vm);` ? if not, please also show the `edit.cshtml`

Comment: Ohh, my mistake. You are right. I was returning Edit.cshtml after post and save. I changed it accordingly and now its working fine. Thank you so much.